# Why does running "setup.py test" run my console script?

Tags: python, setuptools

My very simple example project contains:

```
addtest/
  setup.py
  addtest/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    app.py
```

My `app.py` is just:

```
def main():
    raise SystemExit("Command line entry point called.")
```

My `__main__.py` is just:

```
from addtest.app import main
main()
```

My `setup.py` contains:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='AddTest',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),

    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['addtest = addtest.app:main']
    },
)
```

I would expect that running `python setup.py test` would do nothing, since no unit tests are written. However, running it in a clean virtualenv (Python 3.6.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.1) gives me:

```
$ python setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
writing AddTest.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to AddTest.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to AddTest.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to AddTest.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'AddTest.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'AddTest.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Command line entry point called.
```

Note the `Command line entry point called.` which means it's invoking the console script it generates from my `__main__.py` (or maybe just calling `python -m addtest`).

Why is `setup.py` calling the console script when I want it to run tests? Further inspection of the script's execution shows that `sys.argv` is `['setup.py','test']` - why?

Comment: Regarding `sys.argv` `sys.argv[0]` gives the name of the script being called, and argv provides a list of all the arguments passed to the script so `python setup.py test` gives you `['setup.py', 'test']`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Answer (score 2):

The test scanner in setuptools will look for tests in **any** `*.py` file found in your sub-directories, except for `__init__.py`. Yes, this includes `__main__.py`, it will call `__import__()` on it, causing its main suite to be executed.

If you want to be able to run `python -m addtest` and have that run your `__main__.py` code, you may want to add the standard 'run only if this is really main' protection:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
```

(then, if you do `python -m` the code will run, but it won't run if the file is loaded by `setup.py test`)

Answer (score 1):

The [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) explains how setuptools scans for unit tests by default.

Since, as you say, no unit tests are written or specified, `setuptools` can be using default behavior.

A couple references from the [setuptools docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) that elaborates on this as well as specifies how to set up test suites are below:

1. > `test_loader` If you would like to use a
   >   different way of finding tests to run than what setuptools normally
   >   uses, you can specify a module name and class name in this argument.
   >   
   > ...
   >   The module name and class name must be separated by a :. The default value of this argument is `"setuptools.command.test:ScanningLoader"`. If you want to use the default unittest behavior, you can specify `"unittest:TestLoader"` as your `test_loader` argument instead. ***This will prevent automatic scanning of submodules and subpackages.***
2. > ... `test_suite` A string naming a `unittest.TestCase` subclass (or a package
   >   or module containing one or more of them, or a method of such a
   >   subclass), or naming a function that can be called with no arguments
   >   and returns a `unittest.TestSuite`. 
   > If the named suite is a module, and
   >   the module has an `additional_tests()` function, it is called and the
   >   results are added to the tests to be run. If the named suite is a
   >   package, any submodules and subpackages are recursively added to the
   >   overall test suite.
   >
   > **Specifying this argument enables use of the `test` command** to run the
   >   specified test suite, e.g. via **`setup.py test`**. See the section on the
   >   `test` command below for more details.
   >   
   > ...
   >
   > ```
   >      setup(
   >      # ...
   >      test_suite="my_package.tests.test_all"
   >  )
   > ```

This, in conjunction with [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550011/3544399) on this thread leaves you with at least a couple of options to ensure that `python setup.py test` doesn't run the console script:

1. Configure how `setuptools` looks for test suites.
2. Add `if __name__ == "__main__":` around `main()`

Yet another option may be given by the unit testing library you're using. For example, [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) has an [integration guide for `setuptools`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner) that replaces the `test` command with its own.

**Regarding the sysargs**

`sys.argv` is `['setup.py','test']` because you invoked `python` with the args `setup.py test`

Comment: Can you elaborate on "you haven't defined `test()`"? I'm struggling to find anything resembling this in the Setuptools docs. I was planning to use Py.test rather than the unittest module, and I think they have some configuration tips for this scenario.

Comment: @detly typo, sorry.  I meant you hadn't defined `additional_tests()` - but I was looking at your question as I wrote it.  Editing answer now with the additional reference

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Re. sysargs confusion: for some reason I figured the "main" script had been invoked as a subprocess, I couldn't figure out why else `main()` would be called. Now I see that it was imported, which ran the unguarded `main()` and, as you say, sysargs is trivially going to be what it is.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I added a third option that is what I actually went with. However, I'm using Pytest, which I didn't mention in the question — so it may not be applicable to everyone who reads this, but I expect it might help a lot of folk who are wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify the entry point for test in your setup.py. Otherwise it passes it to the main.py.